# Proving $\limsup$ of sequence $x_n=(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Consider a sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_n=(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n}$. It is clear that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\sup_{k\ge n}(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n}=\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\begin{cases}\frac{n+1}{n} & \text{$n$ even} \\\ \frac{n+2}{n+1} & \text{$n$ odd}\end{cases}=1$$

I am not sure how to prove why it is true.

I think it is enough to prove that $x_n$ is bounded above by $1$ at sufficiently large $n$, i.e. $x_n\le1$ for all but finite $n$. Is that right? I have trouble proving this result because $x_n>1$ for all even $n$.

Comment: "I am not sure how to prove why it is true." Why what is true? [You already said "It is clear"...]

Comment: You obviously can't prove something that is false. This is not what you need to prove though. You need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $x_n<1+\epsilon$ for all but finitely many $n$, and also $x_n>1-\epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. (or you can do it easier if you know that the limsup is the largest partial limit of the sequence)

Comment: @Mark Thanks, that resolved my doubt.

Comment: Your calculation (using the definition of $\limsup$) is sufficient. You don't need to re-prove its result (using another characterization of it).